# Null exception while using AlertDialog to take user to the settings page

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, setting

Im using the method below to take user to the settings page if `GPS` is not enabled. But it *throws an exception* `null`.

```
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    try {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Settings");

        alertDialog.setMessage("Please enable GPS. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        );

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }
        );

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me.

Comment: Post logcat and tell the line number where are you getting null

Comment: **Where** does it throw `NullReferenceException`? Do you know how to use logcat? if so can you locate the error messages and post at least last line where the exception occurs

Comment: make sure mContext is not null and use alertDialog.create().show();

Comment: When I debugged it passed through all the lines and when it reached catch (Exception e) it directly goes to the service class from where I'm calling this method. In the catch block there it throws and exception "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Answer (score 1):

use the following line

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
```

add this line to yours code

```
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    try {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder= new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("GPS Settings");

        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Please enable GPS. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

//added this line
     AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should post only one ans if both are same.

Comment: humble acceptance of yours suggestions. but please do not reduce my point, i am new one at stackoverflow.it was just for his better understanding, wish you a very happy new year-2014 sir :)

Comment: you should extend this answer adding the content of your other answer and remove other one since you shouldn't post multiple answers for a question.

Comment: same to you..it's okay but next time just edit answer.

Comment: sure sir, will remember all these valuable thoughts can you help me to regain my lost points. :)

Comment: i don't know how you lost points but the solution you suggested is good and i was thinking about upvoting before i saw your second (clone) answer. I suggest you delete it keep one so it can be *accepted* as answer

Comment: yes sir sure i have deleted the another one, so please accept this answer and raise points.

Comment: also I don't know who downvoted you. I never downvote anyone in 1.5 years.

Comment: it is ok sir no problem.. but if you can give a vote me now :)

Answer (score 1):

i think u are not initializing the variable **mContext**
 so initialize it with current Activity like **mContext=this;**

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. R&D on this issue indicates that calling an AlertDialog from service is not a good practice. So I'm creating a New Activity with theme @android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog as system overlay window from Service and calling the setting page on click of OK button of that layout with below code.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    this.startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
```

I'm calling this activity from my other service.

```
            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(this,
                    SettingsAlertActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            this.startActivity(intent);
```